# How can I get a server-side control's tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get a server-side control's tag? I'm guessing it's something like below:

```
TextBox textBox=new TextBox();

GetTag(TextBox textBox)
{
    ...
}
```

And the result is something like `<asp:TextBox />` (the control's design time tag).

When I change the control to `CheckBox` then the result should be something like `<asp:CheckBox />`.

Comment: Are you asking for the html text that is rendered?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by control's tag? Is it the control's server-side id?

Comment: Ah, that I wouldn't know, but you could write one with reflection, since the attributes are just properties.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  I am struggling to think of a use case for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MatthewMartin: But the design tags are not properties of the control nor are they stored in private fields; at least I don't see them anywhere so I don't see how reflection will help here.

Comment: TextBox is just the name of the class. Text is just the name of the property. The stuff inside of <asp:TextBox>foo</TextBox> is just the default property. If there are tags inside of the tag, those are also properties of the TextBox class (not relevant for TextBox but for other controls). If they are different, then you'd want to reflect over the Attributes of the class, as some design time features are described in attribute tags.  So reflection would be very relevant.  Also, the base template is held in an attribute tag, also avail by reflection.

Answer (score 2):

There are no methods that can return these tags for you but constructing a dictionary your self should be easy enough.

```
Dictionary<Type, string> d = new Dictionary<Type, string>();
d.Add(typeof(TextBox), @"<\asp:TextBox />");
TextBox t = new TextBox();
string tag= (d[t.GetType()]);
```

And so on...

Comment: I have tried something like this a few days ago. But I want to get the ASP.NET design model's context of the control

Comment: @user1085935: Explain a bit better what do you mean by "ASP.NET design model's context of the control", please.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can use `RenderControl` method</strike>

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
{
    using (HtmlTextWriter textWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
    {
        textBox.RenderControl(textWriter);
    }
}
```

`sb` will have `textBox`'s html content.

**Edit**:

You can get aspx content and find element tag. like this:

```
    String path = Server.MapPath("~/[aspx path]");
    string content = File.ReadAllText(path);

    string controlID = "textBox";
    int startIndex = content.IndexOf("<asp:TextBox ID=\"" + controlID + "\"");
    bool foundEndTag = false;

    string controlTag = "";
    int i = startIndex;
    while (!foundEndTag)
    {
        if (content[i] == '>')
            foundEndTag = true;

        controlTag += content[i];
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: this will return the rendered HTML something like <input type="text" ....> He is asking a way to return something like  "<\asp:TextBox />"

Comment: The result is <input type=\"text\" /> which has been converted to html.

Comment: @user1085935 I wrote simple implementation. You can optimize the code.